# how to get DateTime format to provide Date Month and Year based on Culture of the website?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, sitecore

I am trying to fetch the date based on content Culture of the website in a specific format.

I want to have the Date in the format **Date Month Year**

```
de-DE Culture        1. Oktober 2008
en-US Culture        October 01, 2008
es-ES Culture        01 de octubre de 2008
fr-FR Culture        1 octobre 2008
```

I have tried 
`datetimeObject.ToString("m", contentCultureObject)` which results in

```
de-DE Culture                               01 Oktober
en-US Culture                               October 01
es-ES Culture                               01 octubre
fr-FR Culture                                1 October
```

I have also tried `datetimeObject.ToString("Y", contentCultureObject)` which results in

```
de-DE Culture                             Oktober 2008
en-US Culture                            October, 2008
es-ES Culture                          octubre de 2008
fr-FR Culture                             octobre 2008
```

Basically I want to Combine both "m" and "Y" formats to achieve the desired output.
Please help.

Comment: Please clarify what you want because you say "I want it in Date Month Year" but then shows examples that are in a different order, like "October 01, 2008" which is Month Date Year. So was this an example of what you get, but don't want, or what you actually want?

Comment: If the format you require is not supported out of the box in .NET you have no option but to hardcode the format you want for each supported culture.

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can write your desired Culture 

CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-ES");
    ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "d MMMM yyyy";
    ci.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "d MMMM yyyy h:m:ss";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

//then call
datetimeObject.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is not possible for me because at the moment we have around 28 cultures present in our solution and there is always a possibility of adding more. What I want is a generalized approach which will work for all the cultures. This generalized approach will also save us from code changes and deployment if new language is added.

Comment: maybe this will work for you   CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

Comment: This will make all the cultures to have the same date format, right?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the format you require is suppored by .NET. You probably have no other option than to pick one common format for all cultures, or code a per-culture format.

Comment: @WowoOt: Thanks for the reply. I was able to figure the solution out from your response.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by replacing the `FullDateTimePattern` string.

Here's what I did:

```
string currentCulturePattern = contentCultureObject.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
string requiredPattern = currentCulturePattern.Replace("dddd,", String.Empty).Replace("dddd", String.Empty).Trim();
dateTimeObject.ToString(requiredPattern, contentCultureObject);
```